Glassfish y Jakarta genera archivo
Tengo un problema, he instalado Glassfish 7 usanza Jakarta en Intellij estoy usando un enlace para enviar por petición doGet al servlet no tengo ningún error, todo funciona el detalle es que no me abre otra pestaña en el navegador si no que me guarda un archivo con el contenido que debería mostrar ¿Alguien sabrá a que se debe?
